# Name Disambiguation Issue with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

For the MWE given below:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@Article{Erkus2019,
    author  = {Erkus, A. and Second, B. and Third, C.},
    title   = {This is a paper},
    journal = {Journal of Engineering},
    year    = {2019}}

@Article{Erkus2018,
    author  = {Erkus, A. and Third, B.},
    title   = {This is another paper},
    journal = {Journal of Another Engineering},
    year    = {2018}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Erkus2019}

\cite{Erkus2018}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I get the citations as

> Erkus, Second, et al. 2019
>
> Erkus and Third 2018

The first citation should be

> Erkus, et al. 2019

I do not understand why BibLaTeX considers that there is disambiguity here.

Comment: Use `uniquelist=false`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: My question is why BibLaTeX considers it as a disambiguity.

Comment: Read the documentation, it explains what uniquelist does.